# Visual foce page - sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById not working in lightning?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

```
        var refreshSubtab = function refreshSubtab(result) {
         var tabId = result.id;
         sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId, true);
        }
```

I am using above code to refresh the tab by its id. When I am loading this page in salesforce console, its refreshing the whole page.

When I am trying to move to lightning, its not refreshing. Sforce is not defined in lightning.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179258/sforce-console-refreshprimarytabbyid-not-working-in-lightning/179266 May be this is helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com